# Elasticsearch - List all sources sending messages to ES

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get a list which shows me all sources ES is receiving messages from. I am pretty new with this topic and trying to get deeper into it. I am searching basically for a solution to see the total amount of sources sending logs to my central logging solution and in best case also provided my a list with the source names.

Does anyone have an idea how to get such information querying Elasticsearch?

Comment: Is it possible that this is not really just an Elasticsearch question but actually an ELK question (as in Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, though the solution depends on how your data looks.

Users typically index data in Elasticsearch so that it contains more than just the raw log lines. This is done automatically if you're using [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/beats/filebeat). Otherwise, you'd do something (add a field using Logstash, rely on a host field in syslog, etc) to ensure you have a field that contains your "source" identifier:

```
{
   "message": "my super valuable logline",
   "source": "my_kinda_awesome_app"
}
```

given ^^ you can identify all sources (and record counts!) with a [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) like:

```
{
   "aggs": {
      "my_sources": {
        "terms": { "field": "source" }
      }
   }
}
```

Kibana makes this all easier since you don't need to know/write ES queries and can do stuff visually.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer...basically I am currently using graylog as central logging solution...the system is running pretty unstable so I am trying to get all necessary information from the system before I move to another solution or upgrade the system...since the system is pretty old and managed by a lot of people without deeper knowledge I only have the raw log line. Syslog will be received on a standard input on graylog. Is there a way with only the raw log?

Comment: You could look at doing a series of [filters aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html), one per source. Inside each filter agg would be the search ([match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html), [regex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html), [span](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/span-queries.html), etc) to ID the records by source name/type/id, whatever you'd use.